# Can we get a banner in memory of Steve Jobs on Ask Different?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Can we add a banner on Ask Different in memory of Steve Jobs? RIP.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've posted a banner

> Steve Jobs [passed away](http://apple.com/stevejobs) on October 5th, 2011. Rest in peace.

I'm open to suggestions on the wording/links.

Comment: Seems pretty much perfect. Simple wording, apple.com/stevejobs is probably better than apple.com considering we don't know how long they'll leave their splash in place.

Comment: Thank you. Just. wow.

Comment: Thank you. I would've removed the notification icon though.

Comment: @Dan the system puts that there; I can't remove it. I agree, though.

Comment: IMHO, you should link Steve Jobs' name to the page, not the words "passed away".

Comment: Cannot up-vote enough...

Comment: why is there a tribute on stackoverflow but not here ?

Comment: @mcgrailm There was, but it expired. I re-enabled it.